# why does it show segmentation fault when I tried to use recursion here?

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault

I tried to write a code to calculate how many 1 are there in a number's binary form. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
static int num = 0;
void binary(int target){
    int n = 0;
    int a = 1;
    if(target != 0){
        while(target >= a ){
            n++;
            a = pow(2, n);
        }
        a = pow(2, n-1);
        num++;
        binary(target - a);
    }
}

int main() {
    
    int target = 0;
    scanf("%d", &target);
    binary(target);
    printf("%d",num);
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, this shows segmentation fault when I run it. I don't know where has the code tried to access memories that are not allowed. I figured it might have something to do with the recursion in the `binary` function. Can anyone tell me what have caused the segmentation fault here? Thank you so much. I really can't understand segfaults :(

Comment: What was the test input?

Comment: @Cheatah That would be `(1 << n)` and `(1 << (n-1))`, as `pow(2,x)` does not calculate `x^2`, it calculates `2^x`.

Comment: @ndim -- however, I would still not recommend pow() above

Comment: Still, do not use `pow` in an integer context unless you `round()` the result.

Comment: Generally, always cover the *entire range* of invalid values: `if(target != 0)` ==> `if(target > 0)`. You also allow a negative number input but the algorithm fails.

Comment: The first thing to do is to remove any refererences to `math.h`, `-lm`, and `pow()`. Imprecise floating point operations have no place in programs dealing with integers only. Replace `pow(2,x)` by `(1 << (x))`, then try again to understand your program. And if you are interested in an efficient solution to the problem, see the [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive).

Comment: You should debug to see where the segfault occurs

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `pow` is not a good candiate here due to its signature:

```c
double pow(double x, double y);
```

so any place that you are using `pow`, you are implicitly using floating point numbers. I was able to cause a segfault with the input `1<<31` which is the value `-2147483648`. This will cause your loop to terminate with `n=0`, `a=1`. You then set `a = pow(2, -1)`, but since `a` is an integer, this gets floored down to just `0`. You then recurse with `binary(target - 0)` which might as well just be `binary(target)` again, hence you have an infinite call with no termination.

I'll also leave as a note that recursion for this type of problem is probably not the right tool, unless your goal is to learn about recursion. There is a much more concise and reliable method via a loop and the `&` operator. I would also suggest using unsigned values to avoid issues like this with negative terms.